# Maximum number of hops for a packet in Contiki RPL

Tags: contiki, contiki-ng

I am trying to send a P2P packet from a source to a destination node using classic RPL protocol of Contiki-ng. Unfortunately, the packet can traverse only 8 hops. If the destination is placed somewhere with distance greater than 8 hops, the packet cannot reach to the destination. I tried both the storing (hop-by-hop) and non-storing (source routing). Does anyone know how I can increase this limitation? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Source routing could cause problem if the packet gets too big, but why would if fail with storing mode routing? Did you investigate what causes the packet to be dropped?

Comment: @kfx Thanks for your answer. I checked the problem and found that the problem for the storing mode was the number of max routing. Now there is no problem with the storing mode and hop by hop routing. However, for the non-storing mode I realized that the problem comes from radio limitation. 

`#define CHECK_BUFFER_SPACE(writelen) do { \
  if(hc06_ptr + (writelen) >= PACKETBUF_PAYLOAD_END) { \
    LOG_WARN("Not enough packetbuf space to compress header (%u bytes, %u left). Aborting.\n", \
                (unsigned)(writelen), (unsigned)(PACKETBUF_PAYLOAD_END - hc06_ptr)); \
    return 0;`

Comment: Is there any way to increase the `PACKETBUF_PAYLOAD_END`? I am using cooja mote. I want to change `MAX_PAYLOAD_LEN`, however I think the radio_driver is defined by the platform. Is it possible to change it from cooja mote source code? I really appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: That sounds like a totally different question. Comments on SO are not meant for discussion, but for elaboration of details. If you post that as a new question and provide the relevant details I'll answer it.

Comment: #kfx Thank you! I posted it as a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70314260/radio-payload-limitation-for-cooja-mote-of-contiki-ng